# Derivative of a tabled function on logarithmic scale

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

I have a function in table form (x vs y):

```
data={{0., 260.}, {0.00355759, 259.999}, {0.00711519, 259.999}, {0.0106728,
   145.082}, {0.0142304, 109.453}, {0.017788, 101.983}, {0.0213456, 
  100.415}, {0.0249031, 100.088}, {0.0284607, 100.02}, {0.0320183, 
  100.005}, {0.0355759, 100.001}, {0.0391335, 100.}, {0.0426911, 
  100.}, {0.0462487, 100.}, {0.0498063, 99.9999}, {0.0533639, 
  99.9999}, {0.0569215, 99.9999}, {0.0604791, 99.9999}, {0.0640367, 
  99.9999}, {0.0675943, 99.9999}, {0.0711519, 99.9999}, {0.0747094, 
  99.9999}, {0.078267, 99.9999}, {0.0818246, 99.9999}, {0.0853822, 
  99.9999}, {0.0889398, 99.9999}, {0.0924974, 99.9999}, {0.096055, 
  99.9999}, {0.0996126, 99.9999}, {0.10317, 99.9999}, {0.106728, 
  99.9999}, {0.110285, 99.9999}, {0.113843, 99.9999}, {0.117401, 
  99.9999}, {0.120958, 99.9999}, {0.124516, 99.9999}, {0.128073, 
  99.9999}, {0.131631, 99.9999}, {0.135189, 99.9999}, {0.138746, 
  99.9999}, {0.142304, 99.9999}, {0.145861, 99.9999}, {0.149419, 
  99.9999}, {0.152976, 99.9999}, {0.156534, 99.9999}, {0.160092, 
  99.9999}, {0.163649, 99.9999}, {0.167207, 99.9999}, {0.170764, 
  99.9999}, {0.174322, 99.9999}, {0.17788, 99.9999}, {0.181437, 
  99.9999}, {0.184995, 99.9999}, {0.188552, 99.9999}, {0.19211, 
  99.9999}, {0.195668, 99.9999}, {0.199225, 99.9999}, {0.202783, 
  99.9999}, {0.20634, 99.9999}, {0.209898, 99.9999}, {0.213456, 
  99.9999}, {0.217013, 99.9999}, {0.220571, 99.9999}, {0.224128, 
  99.9999}, {0.227686, 99.9999}, {0.231244, 99.9999}, {0.234801, 
  99.9999}, {0.238359, 99.9999}, {0.241916, 99.9999}, {0.245474, 
  99.9999}, {0.249031, 99.9999}, {0.252589, 99.9999}, {0.256147, 
  99.9999}, {0.259704, 99.9999}, {0.263262, 99.9999}, {0.266819, 
  99.9999}, {0.270377, 99.9999}, {0.273935, 99.9999}, {0.277492, 
  99.9999}, {0.28105, 99.9999}, {0.284607, 99.9999}, {0.288165, 
  99.9999}, {0.291723, 99.9999}, {0.29528, 99.9999}, {0.298838, 
  99.9999}, {0.302395, 99.9999}, {0.305953, 99.9999}, {0.309511, 
  99.9999}, {0.313068, 99.9999}, {0.316626, 99.9999}, {0.320183, 
  99.9999}, {0.323741, 99.9999}, {0.327299, 99.9999}, {0.330856, 
  99.9999}, {0.334414, 99.9999}, {0.337971, 99.9999}, {0.341529, 
  99.9999}, {0.345086, 99.9999}, {0.348644, 99.9999}, {0.352202, 
  99.9999}, {0.355759, 99.9999}, {0.359317, 99.9999}, {0.362874, 
  99.9999}, {0.366432, 99.9999}, {0.36999, 99.9999}, {0.373547, 
  99.9999}, {0.377105, 99.9999}, {0.380662, 99.9999}, {0.38422, 
  99.9999}, {0.387778, 99.9999}, {0.391335, 99.9999}, {0.394893, 
  99.9999}, {0.39845, 99.9999}, {0.402008, 99.9999}, {0.405566, 
  99.9999}, {0.409123, 99.9999}, {0.412681, 99.9999}, {0.416238, 
  99.9999}, {0.419796, 99.9999}, {0.423354, 99.9999}, {0.426911, 
  99.9999}, {0.430469, 99.9999}, {0.434026, 99.9999}, {0.437584, 
  99.9999}, {0.441141, 99.9999}, {0.444699, 99.9999}, {0.448257, 
  99.9999}, {0.451814, 99.9999}, {0.455372, 99.9999}, {0.458929, 
  99.9999}, {0.462487, 99.9999}, {0.466045, 99.9999}, {0.469602, 
  99.9999}, {0.47316, 99.9999}, {0.476717, 99.9999}, {0.480275, 
  99.9999}, {0.483833, 99.9999}, {0.48739, 99.9999}, {0.490948, 
  99.9999}, {0.494505, 99.9999}, {0.498063, 99.9999}, {0.501621, 
  99.9999}, {0.505178, 99.9999}, {0.508736, 99.9999}, {0.512293, 
  99.9999}, {0.515851, 99.9999}, {0.519409, 99.9999}, {0.522966, 
  99.9999}, {0.526524, 99.9999}, {0.530081, 99.9999}, {0.533639, 
  99.9999}, {0.537196, 99.9999}, {0.540754, 99.9999}, {0.544312, 
  99.9999}, {0.547869, 99.9999}, {0.551427, 99.9999}, {0.554984, 
  99.9999}, {0.558542, 99.9999}, {0.5621, 99.9999}, {0.565657, 
  99.9999}, {0.569215, 99.9999}, {0.572772, 99.9999}, {0.57633, 
  99.9999}, {0.579888, 99.9999}, {0.583445, 99.9999}, {0.587003, 
  99.9999}, {0.59056, 99.9999}, {0.594118, 99.9999}, {0.597676, 
  99.9999}, {0.601233, 99.9999}, {0.604791, 99.9999}, {0.608348, 
  99.9999}, {0.611906, 99.9999}, {0.615464, 99.9999}, {0.619021, 
  99.9999}, {0.622579, 99.9999}, {0.626136, 99.9999}, {0.629694, 
  99.9999}, {0.633251, 99.9999}, {0.636809, 99.9999}, {0.640367, 
  99.9999}, {0.643924, 99.9999}, {0.647482, 99.9999}, {0.651039, 
  99.9999}, {0.654597, 99.9999}, {0.658155, 99.9999}, {0.661712, 
  99.9999}, {0.66527, 99.9999}, {0.668827, 99.9999}, {0.672385, 
  99.9999}, {0.675943, 99.9999}, {0.6795, 99.9999}, {0.683058, 
  99.9999}, {0.686615, 99.9999}, {0.690173, 99.9999}, {0.693731, 
  99.9999}, {0.697288, 99.9999}, {0.700846, 99.9999}, {0.704403, 
  99.9999}, {0.707961, 99.9999}, {0.711519, 99.9999}, {0.715076, 
  99.9999}, {0.718634, 99.9999}, {0.722191, 99.9999}, {0.725749, 
  99.9999}, {0.729306, 99.9999}, {0.732864, 99.9999}, {0.736422, 
  99.9999}, {0.739979, 99.9999}, {0.743537, 99.9999}, {0.747094, 
  99.9999}, {0.750652, 99.9999}, {0.75421, 99.9999}, {0.757767, 
  99.9999}, {0.761325, 99.9999}, {0.764882, 99.9999}, {0.76844, 
  99.9999}, {0.771998, 99.9999}, {0.775555, 99.9999}, {0.779113, 
  99.9999}, {0.78267, 99.9999}, {0.786228, 99.9999}, {0.789786, 
  99.9999}, {0.793343, 99.9999}, {0.796901, 99.9997}, {0.800458, 
  99.9995}, {0.804016, 99.9993}, {0.807574, 99.9991}, {0.811131, 
  99.9989}, {0.814689, 99.9987}, {0.818246, 99.9984}, {0.821804, 
  99.9982}, {0.825361, 99.998}, {0.828919, 99.9978}, {0.832477, 
  99.9976}, {0.836034, 99.9974}, {0.839592, 99.9972}, {0.843149, 
  99.997}, {0.846707, 99.9968}, {0.850265, 99.9965}, {0.853822, 
  99.9963}, {0.85738, 99.9961}, {0.860937, 99.9959}, {0.864495, 
  99.9957}, {0.868053, 99.9955}, {0.87161, 99.9953}, {0.875168, 
  99.9951}, {0.878725, 99.9948}, {0.882283, 99.9946}, {0.885841, 
  99.9944}, {0.889398, 99.9942}, {0.892956, 99.994}, {0.896513, 
  46.2395}, {0.900071, 33.4084}, {0.903629, 30.7159}, {0.907186, 
  30.1504}, {0.910744, 30.0323}, {0.914301, 30.007}, {0.917859, 
  30.0015}, {0.921416, 30.0002}, {0.924974, 29.9999}, {0.928532, 
  29.9998}, {0.932089, 30.}, {0.935647, 30.}, {0.939204, 
  30.}, {0.942762, 30.}, {0.94632, 30.}, {0.949877, 30.}, {0.953435, 
  30.}, {0.956992, 30.}, {0.96055, 30.}, {0.964108, 30.}, {0.967665, 
  30.}, {0.971223, 30.}, {0.97478, 30.}, {0.978338, 30.}, {0.981896, 
  30.}, {0.985453, 30.}, {0.989011, 30.}, {0.992568, 30.}, {0.996126, 
  30.}, {0.999684, 30.}, {1.00324, 30.}, {1.0068, 30.}, {1.01036, 
  30.}, {1.01391, 30.}, {1.01747, 30.}, {1.02103, 30.}, {1.02459, 
  30.}, {1.02814, 30.}, {1.0317, 30.}, {1.03526, 30.}, {1.03882, 
  30.}, {1.04237, 30.}, {1.04593, 30.}, {1.04949, 30.}, {1.05305, 
  30.}, {1.05661, 30.}, {1.06016, 30.}, {1.06372, 30.}, {1.06728, 
  30.}, {1.07084, 30.}, {1.07439, 30.}, {1.07795, 30.}, {1.08151, 
  30.}, {1.08507, 30.}, {1.08862, 30.}, {1.09218, 30.}, {1.09574, 
  30.}, {1.0993, 30.}, {1.10285, 30.}, {1.10641, 30.}, {1.10997, 
  30.}, {1.11353, 30.}, {1.11708, 30.}, {1.12064, 30.}, {1.1242, 
  30.}, {1.12776, 30.}, {1.13131, 30.}, {1.13487, 30.}, {1.13843, 
  30.}, {1.14199, 30.}, {1.14554, 30.}, {1.1491, 30.}, {1.15266, 
  30.}, {1.15622, 30.}, {1.15978, 30.}, {1.16333, 30.}, {1.16689, 
  30.}, {1.17045, 30.}, {1.17401, 30.}, {1.17756, 30.}, {1.18112, 
  30.}, {1.18468, 30.}, {1.18824, 30.}, {1.19179, 30.}, {1.19535, 
  30.}, {1.19891, 30.}, {1.20247, 30.}, {1.20602, 30.}, {1.20958, 
  30.}, {1.21314, 30.}, {1.2167, 30.}, {1.22025, 30.}, {1.22381, 
  30.}, {1.22737, 30.}, {1.23093, 30.}, {1.23448, 30.}, {1.23804, 
  30.}, {1.2416, 30.}, {1.24516, 30.}, {1.24872, 30.}, {1.25227, 
  30.}, {1.25583, 30.}, {1.25939, 30.}, {1.26295, 30.}, {1.2665, 
  30.}, {1.27006, 30.}, {1.27362, 30.}, {1.27718, 30.}, {1.28073, 
  30.}, {1.28429, 30.}, {1.28785, 30.}, {1.29141, 30.}, {1.29496, 
  30.}, {1.29852, 30.}, {1.30208, 30.}, {1.30564, 30.}, {1.30919, 
  30.}, {1.31275, 30.}, {1.31631, 30.}, {1.31987, 30.}, {1.32342, 
  30.}, {1.32698, 30.}, {1.33054, 30.}, {1.3341, 30.}, {1.33765, 
  30.}, {1.34121, 30.}, {1.34477, 30.}, {1.34833, 30.}, {1.35189, 
  30.}, {1.35544, 30.}, {1.359, 30.}, {1.36256, 30.}, {1.36612, 30.}, 
 {1.36967, 30.}, {1.37323, 30.}, {1.37679, 30.}, {1.38035, 
  30.}, {1.3839, 30.}, {1.38746, 30.}, {1.39102, 30.}, {1.39458, 
  30.}, {1.39813, 30.}, {1.40169, 30.}, {1.40525, 30.}, {1.40881, 
  30.}, {1.41236, 30.}, {1.41592, 30.}, {1.41948, 30.}, {1.42304, 
  30.}, {1.42659, 30.}, {1.43015, 30.}, {1.43371, 30.}, {1.43727, 
  30.}, {1.44083, 30.}, {1.44438, 30.}, {1.44794, 30.}, {1.4515, 
  30.}, {1.45506, 30.}, {1.45861, 30.}, {1.46217, 30.}, {1.46573, 
  30.}, {1.46929, 30.}, {1.47284, 30.}, {1.4764, 30.}, {1.47996, 
  30.}, {1.48352, 30.}, {1.48707, 30.}, {1.49063, 30.}, {1.49419, 
  30.}, {1.49775, 30.}, {1.5013, 30.}, {1.50486, 30.}, {1.50842, 
  30.}, {1.51198, 30.}, {1.51553, 30.}, {1.51909, 30.}, {1.52265, 
  30.}, {1.52621, 30.}, {1.52976, 30.}, {1.53332, 30.}, {1.53688, 
  30.}, {1.54044, 30.}, {1.544, 30.}, {1.54755, 30.}, {1.55111, 
  30.}, {1.55467, 30.}, {1.55823, 30.}, {1.56178, 30.}, {1.56534, 
  30.}, {1.5689, 30.}, {1.57246, 30.}, {1.57601, 30.}, {1.57957, 
  30.}, {1.58313, 30.}, {1.58669, 30.}, {1.59024, 30.}, {1.5938, 
  30.}, {1.59736, 30.}, {1.60092, 30.}, {1.60447, 30.}, {1.60803, 
  30.}, {1.61159, 30.}, {1.61515, 30.}, {1.6187, 30.}, {1.62226, 
  30.}, {1.62582, 30.}, {1.62938, 30.}, {1.63294, 30.}, {1.63649, 
  30.}, {1.64005, 30.}, {1.64361, 30.}, {1.64717, 30.}, {1.65072, 
  30.}, {1.65428, 30.}, {1.65784, 30.}, {1.6614, 30.}, {1.66495, 
  30.}, {1.66851, 30.}, {1.67207, 30.}, {1.67563, 30.}, {1.67918, 
  30.}, {1.68274, 30.}, {1.6863, 30.}, {1.68986, 29.9999}, {1.69341, 
  29.9999}, {1.69697, 29.9999}, {1.70053, 29.9999}, {1.70409, 
  29.9999}, {1.70764, 29.9999}, {1.7112, 29.9999}, {1.71476, 
  29.9999}, {1.71832, 29.9998}, {1.72187, 29.9998}, {1.72543, 
  29.9998}, {1.72899, 29.9998}, {1.73255, 29.9998}, {1.73611, 
  29.9998}, {1.73966, 29.9998}, {1.74322, 29.9997}, {1.74678, 
  29.9997}, {1.75034, 29.9997}, {1.75389, 29.9997}, {1.75745, 
  29.9997}, {1.76101, 29.9997}, {1.76457, 29.9997}, {1.76812, 
  29.9997}, {1.77168, 29.9996}, {1.77524, 29.9996}, {1.7788, 0}}
```

By plotting it with a log abscissa axis, it becomes obvious that this function changes steeply at two x-values. I would like to calculate the first derivative of this functions (g[x]). Therefore, as often, I did:

```
dataInt = Interpolation[data];
g[x_] = D[dataInt[x], {x, 1}];
```

Nevertheless, the function g[x] when plotted on a Log-Log plane shows a lot of 'breaks' that are of numerical origin. How to get rid of them and do this properly?

Comment: Is your function correct. It looks rather like a step function than a smooth function.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see how your data is "smooth" when plotted on a logarithmic x-axis, but I can help with the derivative.

```
$Version
"13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"
```

When using `Interpolation` you have to critically question your choices. Without any specified options, `Interpolation` tries to fit all your given data. This may lead to undesirable artifacts, as in this example:

```
interpoldata = Interpolation[data];
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}], 
 Plot[interpoldata[x], {x, 0, 1.7788}]]
```

Gives:

[image]

Notice the spikes in the Interpolation function? When you build your derivative of this function, you will get a positive slope where there is none in your data.
This can be remedied by setting `InterpolationOrder->1`, giving you linear interpolation between your data points:

```
interpoldata = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}], 
 Plot[interpoldata[x], {x, 0, 1.7788}]]
```

Gives:

[image]

And with appropriate settings for `Interpolation` you easily get the derivative:

```
interpoldata = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Plot[interpoldata'[x], {x, 0, 1.7788}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. what I meant with 'smooth' is actually 'without spikes'. Setting InterpolationOrder to 1 does help. However, if I plot your solution using LogLogPlot, I still see a lot of spikes.

Comment: It is certainly possible that I do not fully understand the question you are asking then. Maybe you should clarify in your opening post.

Comment: Is it clear now?